# While Updating dexguard version throw error - Crashlytics plugin is applied before the DexGuard plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dexguard

When updating dexguard version i got error ---- Crashlytics plugin is applied before the DexGuard plugin.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1' 

 dexguard version 8.5.01

my plugins --

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 
'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

apply plugin: 'dexguard'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes in your plugin squences. Please dexguard after application plugin. Basically you need to keep fabric plugin after dexguard plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dexguard' 
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' 
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
```